# How can I remove the all the characters after second "." from the right in excel?

Tags: excel, formula

How can I remove all the characters after the second "." from the right in excel?

E.g I have a file called dr_kk's_office_on_level_12_omb.msg.1370398310562.ver1 and I want to remove '.1370398310562.ver1' .. meaning second full stop "." from the right including the full stop.

May I know how I should go about this? Thanks

Comment: This has been asked before so searching on here would give you a couple of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

```
==LEFT(A5,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A5,".","~",LEN(A5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A5,".",""))-1))-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Should work for this instance I assume, but this does not consider *"second "." from the right"*. In theory there could be more dots, which means you probably meant something like `=LEFT(A1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))-1))-1)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
=LEFT(A3,FIND(".",A3,FIND(".",A3)+1)-1)
```

1. Use "FIND"function as below:

```
FIND(".",A3)
```

to get the position of first "."

2. Use "FIND" function, as below:

```
FIND(".",A3,FIND(".",A3)+1)
```

to get the position of second "."

3. Use Left Function, with the position of Second "."

```
LEFT(A3,FIND(".",A3,FIND(".",A3)+1)-1)
```

to remove the string after Second ".",
-1 is to include the second "." in the process of removing.

Comment: As with the other answer this does not take into account *" the second "." from the right"*. It might however work in this instance.